# Determining the precision of a range

Tags: mean, uncertainty, precision

Supposing that I have 2 measured values which cover a range Y and Z and the actual value "X" is somewhere in the middle. How can I calculate the precision of the range? I expected to theoretically measure the same value when I measured both Y and Z, but they are quiet far apart.

Comment: Welcome to CV! Your question seems too broad. Do you have examples of the data you are dealing with?

Comment: The midrange ($(Y+Z)/2$ in your notation) of a sample of size $n=2$ is the same as sample mean. Are _those_ the two quantities you thought would be the same? Are you trying to use the midrange to estimate the population center? Are your data normal? Symmetrical?